# ERC20 Network Fee

Tags: erc-20

I have tried to withdraw 544K from my coinbase wallet, using ERc20, counbade is telling me that my withdraw amount caused the ERC20 Network to get congested, and it also triggered a fee of 20% fee on withdraw amount. And coinbase is telling me that my Funds are frozen in ERC20 until I
Pay the fee. I asked them to take the fee from my balance, they said no you have to inject the fee to release my funds, and I have seven days to do it otherwise my funds will disappear in ERC20. What do I do? Please advise

Comment: The problem isn't clear from the limited data provided. It could be a legit non-custodial wallet that uses a third party service for staking where you have to pay the transaction fees. Also it could be a scam. You never had any profit, they demand more fees but they will never return anything to you.

Answer (score 0):

"Unusual Fee Requests"&"Sense of Urgency" are often signs or characteristics of a scam.